# Lookup Field whose value depends on the value of another lookup field

Tags: sql, ms-access, lookupfield

I'm trying to make a field in Access 2013 where the selection of a set of team members is dependent upon the team that was selected in the same record.  I've made the following SQL statement as my Row Source:

```
SELECT [Tech Name] 
FROM tblTechs 
WHERE tblWorkOrder.[Team Responsible:]=tblTechs.[Team];
```

Where tblTechs.[Tech Name] is the field of where the list of options is called from and tblWork Order.[Team Responsible:] is the field that I want to inform the list options for the given field in the same table.

The Tech table contains the field "Team" which contains the same reference that informs [Team Responsible:] in the Work Order table.

Once again, any help you guys could provide would be great.

Comment: why don't you make a pivot table to do this?

Comment: The people that will ultimately use this won't be able to use a pivot table.  This query will be the engine for something shinier with bright buttons and little to no editability.